# GROUP BY con valores nulos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

```
SELECT s.producto,s.entrada AS entrada,r.salida AS salida,s.mes,s.anio  AS anio,s.entrada-r.salida AS total 
FROM (SELECT MONTH ( fecha ) AS mes,YEAR(fecha) AS anio,    producto,COALESCE(SUM(cantidad),0) AS entrada FROM eProductoTerminado 
WHERE ingresosalida='Ingreso' AND fecha BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND  '2017-12-31' GROUP BY producto,anio ORDER BY producto) AS s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MONTH ( fecha ) AS mes,YEAR(fecha) AS anio,producto,COALESCE(SUM(cantidad),0) AS salida FROM eProductoTerminado 
WHERE ingresosalida='Salida' AND fecha BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'  GROUP BY producto,anio ORDER BY producto) AS r ON
s.producto=r.producto AND s.mes=r.mes AND s.anio=r.anio
```

tengo esta sentencia SQL, el problema de esta sentencia es que en el WHERE ingresosalida='Salida' en el campo de cantidad tengo un valor NULL y tengo otro valor que si tiene valor, pero al agrupar el valor+null (ojo no es una suma, es un GROUP BY) en el resultado me lo toma como el NULL y no como el valor , ya busque como hacerlo pero solo sale en el caso de cuando se hace un SUM.

Es MYSQL

Comment: no entiendo bien. Si cantidad es NULL, y estás sumando cantidad y agrupando por otras columnas, a qué te refieres con "no es una suma es un group by"?

Comment: que no estoy usano SUM si no el group by agrupa las cantidades y eso es como si fuera una suma , no se si me di a entender jaja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomiendo que formatees correctamente tu código, esto hace más fácil su mantención y también permite que los usuarios del sitio te podamos ayudar más rápidamente. Tu código formateado sería el siguiente:

```
SELECT  s.producto,
        s.entrada AS entrada,
        r.salida AS salida,
        s.mes,
        s.anio AS anio,
        s.entrada-r.salida AS total 
FROM (  SELECT  MONTH(fecha) AS mes,
                YEAR(fecha) AS anio,    
                producto,
                COALESCE(SUM(cantidad),0) AS entrada 
        FROM eProductoTerminado 
        WHERE ingresosalida = 'Ingreso' 
        AND fecha BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' 
        GROUP BY producto,
                 anio 
        ORDER BY producto) AS s
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  MONTH(fecha) AS mes,
                    YEAR(fecha) AS anio,
                    producto,
                    COALESCE(SUM(cantidad),0) AS salida 
            FROM eProductoTerminado 
            WHERE ingresosalida='Salida' 
            AND fecha BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'  
            GROUP BY producto,
                     anio 
            ORDER BY producto) AS r 
    ON s.producto = r.producto 
    AND s.mes = r.mes 
    AND s.anio = r.anio
```

Un par de recomendaciones generales: Primero que todo, trata de entender correctamente cómo funcionan las agregaciones en general, por favor, no confíes en el comportamiento no ANSI de MySQL al momento de usar `GROUP BY`. Siempre es conveniente que escribas en forma explícita todas las columnas que necesitan estar en el `GROUP BY` (son todas aquellas que no están contenidas en alguna función de agregación).

Además, en tu caso en particular, el `LEFT JOIN` con la subquery sobre la misma tabla es completamente innecesario, puedes usar por ejemplo la expresión `CASE WHEN` dentro de la función de agregación.

De esta forma, tu código se puede reescribir así:

```
SELECT  producto,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ingresosalida = 'Ingreso' THEN cantidad ELSE 0 END),0) AS entrada,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ingresosalida = 'Salida' THEN cantidad ELSE 0 END),0) AS salida,
        MONTH(fecha) AS mes,
        YEAR(fecha) AS anio,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ingresosalida = 'Ingreso' THEN 1 
                          WHEN ingresosalida = 'Salida' THEN -1 END * cantidad),0) AS total
FROM eProductoTerminado 
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' 
GROUP BY producto,
         MONTH(fecha),
         YEAR(fecha);
```

Comment: me dio error  de sistaxis jaja

Comment: pero ya lo resolvi, eran comas que faltaban, no manches me salvaste la vida enserio, si salio asi, al principio crei que no estaba funcionando bien pero ya entendi porque me salia otros resultado que no eran, enserio me salvaste la vida , muchisisimas gracias!

Comment: @RodrigoLoy Me alegro que te haya servido. Y que bueno que hayas entendido también

Answer (score 1):

si existe un campo en `NULL` en un `row` no te lo sumará, te recomiendo, sabiendo que ese campo puede están en `NULL` y no te afectaría que fuera 0, poner `IFNULL(campo, 0)`. (gracias al otro comentario esta formateado, revisa el campo que necesitas)

```
SELECT  s.producto,
        s.entrada AS entrada,
        r.salida AS salida,
        s.mes,
        s.anio AS anio,
        s.entrada-r.salida AS total 
FROM (  SELECT  MONTH(fecha) AS mes,
                YEAR(fecha) AS anio,    
                producto,
                COALESCE(SUM(cantidad),0) AS entrada 
        FROM eProductoTerminado 
        WHERE ingresosalida = 'Ingreso' 
        AND fecha BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' 
        GROUP BY producto,
                 anio 
        ORDER BY producto) AS s
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  MONTH(fecha) AS mes,
                    YEAR(fecha) AS anio,
                    producto,
                    COALESCE(SUM(IFNULL(cantidad,0)),0) AS salida 
            FROM eProductoTerminado 
            WHERE ingresosalida='Salida' 
            AND fecha BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'  
            GROUP BY producto,
                     anio 
            ORDER BY producto) AS r 
    ON s.producto = r.producto 
    AND s.mes = r.mes 
    AND s.anio = r.anio
```